# javascript: How to make all links on youtube to open in new tab

Tags: javascript, firefox

Example I have this youtube link which shows search results

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=himalayas
```

I am using firefox and its developer tools

I am trying to run this js script to make left click any link on the page to open in a new tab

code1

```
var e = document.createElement("base");
e.target = "_blank";
document.head.appendChild(e);
```

Code2

```
var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
     links[i].target = "_blank";
}
```

Both of them add the target attribute

But after this script also i cannot open the link on new tab when left clicking

Any idea how can i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to

1. remove the `yt-simple-endpoint` class that exists on the a href tags

```
    var links = document.links;
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
         links[i].classList.remove('yt-simple-endpoint')
         links[i].target = "_blank";
    }
```

If you remove the class it affects the styling, but you can always fix that by re-adding the styles.

or

2. remove the click event listener that's attached to `<ytd-app>`

I don't think it's easy to remove event listeners in Firefox. You might be able to using Firebug. Chrome has getEventListeners, so you can run

```
const ytdApp = document.getElementsByTagName('ytd-app')[0]
ytdApp.removeEventListener('click', getEventListeners(ytdApp).click[0].listener)

var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].classList.remove('yt-simple-endpoint')
    links[i].target = "_blank";
}
```